# Return a variable object (dynamic?)

Tags: c#, dynamic, return-value

i am trying to find the best way to do this:

I have an abstract class A, and many concrete derived classes, lets call them D1..DN.
Each derived class, needs a method which takes a string, parses it, and returns a type depending on which concrete class it is. So since i dont know the return type in the Abstract class, i cant define the function normally.
What i have found is the dynamic keyword, i could so something like this:

public dynamic Parse();  in my abstract class
And then each concrete class can override it and return any type they want, however, on the app using this i would like to know which is the returned type so this is aint good at all.

Any other option? The worse scenario would be not doing a polymorphism and on my main app ask the abstract class on a huge if to check what class it is and set the return type accordingly.

EDIT: Bad design, should re think the problem and find a better approach with polymorphism. Sorry for your time :). In the worst case i will go with the return object and millions of lines with ifs

Comment: Think of `dynamic` as `object` with a magical wrapper for runtime reflection using normal identifiers .. for all normal cases, stay with nominative typing. (Remember that `dynamic` is a relatively new C# concept.)

Comment: can you show some code on how you intend to use this? If you get an object of your base class  A, lets call it a.... then go  a.Parse(""), and end up with any possible type,  then you're going to move the "lots of if statements" to the return type.

Comment: I have no code since im still thinking which way should i go on.
What im trying to accomplish is that the method returns an unknown type, depending on the derived class it is.
So i cant declare the return type of the method in the abstract class, because lets say D1 returns int, D2 returns String, D3 returns a Date and so on..

Comment: well, you can make the return type 'object', and you can do what you want,  but it will simply create a problem elsewhere as you now have to work out what to do with this object you've created.  Usually you'd have things return something with a common interface.  Not completely separate types with nothing in common.  It will lead you to have to write "if this is an int, do int stuff, otherwise if string do string stuff, otherwise if its a datetime, do datetime stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to return any kind of object, you can

```
public abstract object Parse(string s);
```

then subclasses can return whatever they like.... but usually this would be a BAD design.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for generics:

```
abstract class ParserBase<T> {
    public abstract T Parse(string input);
}

abstract class ThingyParser : ParserBase<Thingy> {
    public override Thingy Parse(string input);
}
```

Comment: depends on how he intended to use this.... if he is expecting to have an object that is of  the type of his abstract base type, then calls parse on it and result in some mystery object.... then this won't really help.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: If so, he has bigger problems.  (and can use an interface to get to those problems)

Comment: My guess is he has bigger problems, and from the way he's worded it, an interface wouldn't work either as he has said ANY type can be returned.

Comment: I dont think this will work, because i would need to know T.
What i need is:
A method will give me a List<Base>, then i will iterate through it, and call the parse method, which will give me an int, a date, or w/e it should be returning. But i think this is impossible i should go and re thing the design.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance and contra-variant concept might work:

```
    public abstract BaseClass Parse(string s);
```

So, if you return any type inherited from base, wont be a problem.